# ¿Como puedo cambiar el tipo de SESION (Persistence) en mi aplicacion con firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic

Estoy intentando cambiar el tipo de sesión con ionic y firebase. he leído la documentación pero sigo son poder aplicarlo correctamente.
Estoy utilizando el código de la documentación de firebase. Pero como soy nuevo es esto quisiera saber que librerías debo importar.

Este es mi metodo iniciar Sesion:

signInUser(){

```
this.fire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.user.value, this.password.value)
  .then(data =>{
    this.alert('Succes! you\'re logged in');
    this.navCtrl.setRoot( AddpromoPage );
    //user is logged in
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.alert(error.message);
  })
```

}

como puedo agregar el método de persistencia:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(function() {
    return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence?hl=es-419

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Podrías anexar el código que has hecho para poder apoyarte mejor?

Comment: Hola Luis bienvenido a StackOverFlow en Español, por favor te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mas sobre el sitio y así obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Tambien te invito que revises [ask]. Podrías editar la pregunta y agregar el código que has utilizado?

Comment: Para entender mejor.. Lo que necesitas es que la sesión quede abierta, para no tener que loguearte de nuevo al reabrir la aplicación? O lo contrario?